# Storing GoogleMap in ViewModel

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I started to implement `Jetpack Compose` and curious: is it a good decision to store `GoogleMap` in `ViewModel`? Checking its internals, I didn't find it contains any `Context`, therefore it should be context-unaware and can be stored in `VM`.
The sample code is:

```
class MapViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    val gMapAsync = MutableLiveData<GoogleMap>()
}

@Composable
fun MapViewContainer(
    viewModel: MapViewModel
) {
    val map = rememberMapViewWithLifecycle()
    AndroidView({ map }) { mapView: MapView ->
        mapView.getMapAsync {
            viewModel.gMapAsync.value = it
        }
    }
}
```

The other way I see is to use an internal variable or something else (like callbacks):

```
internal val gMapAsync = MutableLiveData<GoogleMap>()
```

Comment: I didn't try that, but there is a video by Mitch that touches exactly that subject. This video explains how to store GoogleMap in Viewmodel and why it is safe:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8OqN-JqWlQ&ab_channel=CodingWithMitch

Answer (score 0):

I found `Context` in one of its subclasses, therefore it looks like a not good idea to store `GoogleMap` in `ViewModel`

```
package com.google.android.libraries.maps.ka;

public class zzba implements zzax, zze, zzbm {
    private final Context zzv;
```